# Eclipse 2021-12 not connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am using a legacy project which uses spring v4.2.3 and hibernate v4.0.1. The project works like a charm on Eclipse neon version, however, when trying to connect with the eclipse 2021-12 it shows that unable to connect to underlying database, all the rest of the configs are read right in terms of controllers mapping and everything. I am using java 8 and tomcat 7. The db properties are stored in .properties file. Is there anything that needs to be added in the project or this wont work at all?

[image]

Comment: Show the error message itself.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add a jpa repository to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didnt work too!